# Until Loop Checking a Cell Isn't Empty in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

Currently I have code that checks if the cell to the right of the first ")" found is empty and if it isn't, it shifts the "A" column down. I can't seem to figure out how to make this keep running until the cell to the right of the paren is empty. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
Sub SeekParen()
    Dim C As Range, wheree As Range, whatt As String
    whatt = ")"
    Set C = Range("A1:A10")
    Set wheree = C.Find(what:=whatt, after:=C(1)).Offset(0, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(wheree.Address(0, 0)) Then
        Range("A2").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
Sub SeekParen()
Dim C As Range, wheree As Range
Dim whatt As String
Dim TotalCycle As Long, CounterCycle As Long
whatt = ")"
Set C = Range("A1:A10")

Set wheree = C.Find(what:=whatt, after:=C(1)).Offset(0, 1)
TotalCycle = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(C, whatt)
For CounterCycle = 1 To TotalCycle
If wheree.Value <> "" Then
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Set wheree = C.Find(what:=whatt, after:=C(wheree.Row)).Offset(0, 1)
Else
Exit For
End If
Next CounterCycle
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. This works somewhat well. For some reason if you run it more than once it brings the paren to where I want it but the first time, it goes one cell above the desired location. Any ideas?

Comment: Since the items are going to be not the same size due to the first time execution, that is an expected behavior. You would need to insert an entire row instead of only inserting in the 1st column.